# How to prevent Chrome from focusing a contenteditable element when its caret is moved to the end?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Consider this plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jbk3pGr7nfpplEvCKOMx?p=preview

The contenteditable element is not focused. Now the first button sets the caret in the contenteditable element to the end. (The second button focuses the element). In firefox 25, setting the caret does not focus (set active) the element; in Chrome 31 it does. How can I prevent that from happen? Setting blur after setting the caret is one option, however this is unreliable when the setting the caret is done programatically and not from a user action, or if I have a focus listener on the element (that is still going to be fired).

Comment: Why is blurring afterwards unreliable?

Comment: When I blur, any other focus event on the element is still fired. I'd still need a way to tell the focus event not to fire in specific circumstances. What I really need is a way to prevent the focus from happening.

Comment: I'd like an answer to this to be honest.